# Insert instructions into component event

Tags: delphi, components

I want to extend TTimer's functionality by inserting an option how manny times the timer can execute.

My problem is that i need to do this inside the OnTimer() event. Is there a way i can override this event thus keeping it original functionality ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most good components have a protected virtual or dynamic method that does nothing but call the corresponding event. That way, descendants can insert their own event-related code while still leaving the actual event available for the end user of the component when it's placed on a form.

In the case of `TTimer`, the method that invokes the `OnTimer` event is [`Timer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer.Timer). Create a descendant of `TTimer` and override that method. Check how many times you've already called the function, and if you're still below the limit, then call `inherited`.